# How to query target of all Finder aliases?

Tags: macos, alias, finder, xattr

Mac OSX 10.6

I've got some aliases that are pointing to the wrong volume. I'd like to search my whole hierarchy for such aliases. They're aliases, not symlinks, so I *can't* just do `find / -type l -ls | grep badVolumeName`.

It seems that aliases have a com.apple.ResourceFork, but querying this with `xattr` gives me binary data. Is there a way to dump the target of the alias as text so I can grep for the bad volume name? Or what's another way to do this?

Comment: It would probably be better to ask this on [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

To find alias files you can make use of [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4943533). First, create a script `is_alias.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
[ "$(mdls -raw -name kMDItemKind "$1")" = "Alias" ]
```

and then run

```
find . -type f -exec ./is_alias.sh {} \; -print
```

Getting the path of an alias seems quite difficult.

[Someone](http://pudge.net/glob/2003/02/useperl-10437.html) has posted a solution using MacPerl, but as I do not have MacPerl I haven't tested this and don't know whether it works.

There is a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2656/53198) on AskDifferent, with several different suggestions, but none of them seem to actually solve the problem. The Applescript answer is okay, but the key operation, getting the "original item" of an alias file, doesn't seem to work for broken aliases.

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606255/reading-alias-files) which might have some Cocoa solutions.

Answer (score 0):

the bash script didn't work for me because I was running it in zsh. so I ran the below perl script with find:

```bash
find . -type f -print0|xargs -0 isAlias.pl
```

and here's the perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while ( my $name = shift @ARGV ) {
  #print $name;

  open my $fh, "-|", ( 'mdls', '-n', 'kMDItemKind', '--', $name ) or die "Failed spawning mdls on '$name': $!";
  my @output_lines = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
  #print " ", scalar @output_lines, " ";
  #print "'", @output_lines, "'\n";
  #chomp $output_lines[0];
  
  $output_lines[0] =~ m/kMDItemKind = "([^"]+)"/ or die "Failed getting ItemKind: $!";

  my $kind = $1;

  if ($kind =~ m/Alias/) {
    print "'$name' is an alias\n";
  }
  #else {
  #    print "\n";
  #}
}
```